# variable for 32 and 64bits environments

Tags: windows, batch-file

im trying to make a simple .bat program that erase in both 32 and 64bits environments Panda Software, the thing is that in 32 bits the path is Program Files (x86) and in 64 is Program Files

I have this :

```
@echo off

cd "C:\%programfiles%\Panda Software\Panda Administrator 3\Pavinst\Plagent"

start pavagent.exe -a:uninstall -DeleteQtine:1

cd "C:\Program Files\Panda Software\AVTC\Install"

start uninst.exe -a:uninstall -DeleteQtine:1

TIMEOUT /T 3
```

¿Could this work for both environments?
¿How can i make this work that will diferentiate if the system is 32 or 64 bits depending on the computers?

It's only to delete Panda in 200PCs, ¿how can it be made for the batch to diferentiate or maybe say : IF you're 32bits do this else if youre 64bits do this?

Please a little help will be appreciated folks.

Regards

Comment: Use an `IF EXIST` command to see which path it is installed in. Or I bet there is a common registry entry that you could query that would tell you the path it is installed in.

Comment: Answer seems to be here : https://superuser.com/a/142416

Comment: @RafaelUP Please read Microsoft's MSDN article [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274.aspx) and take a look on answer on [Batch file behaves differently when ran from a SFX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38138874/3074564). A user has usually the freedom to install an application into any directory during the installation and must not use the default installation path. So it would be most likely better to get the installation location directly from Windows registry with execution of a `reg query` in a `for` loop.

Comment: Usually the registry install location or uninstall key is found under a non specific _{GUID String}_ which could be difficult to determine unless all PC's were installed using the same product installer. _Even looking for the key may confuse due to having both 32bit and 64bit registry locations_.

Answer (score 1):

ask Windows, whether it's running 32 bit or 64 bit.

```
wmic os get OsArchitecture |find "64" >nul && ( 
  echo insert code for 64bit
) || (
  echo insert code for 32bit
)
```

`&&` works as "if previous command (`find`) was successful, then..."
`||` works as "if previous command (`find`) failed, then..."

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Squashman's comment of using an `IF EXIST`:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "PAD=Panda Software"
Set "PPL=Panda Administrator 3\Pavinst\Plagent\pavagent.exe"
Set "PAU=AVTC\Install\uninst.exe"
Set "PUS=-A:UnInstall -DeleteQtine:1"

For %%A In ("%ProgramFiles%" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%") Do (
    If Exist "%%~A\%PPL%" "%%~A\%PPL%" %PUS%
    If Exist "%%~A\%PAU%" "%%~A\%PAU%" %PUS%)
```

Please understand that this answer is relative to performing the specific commands you've shown; it is not a knowledgebase article on how to uninstall your antivrus products, *for that I provide no support*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! managed to figure this with you help and now we'll start with this to perform our main task, which is a migration.

Thank you a lot.